# Call vc++ dll in c# by .def file(by ordinal no's)

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll

I have a dll in vc++ 9.0 Now I have to call the function of this dll in our c# application,but the problem is that we have to use .def file to export the functions.

```
EXPORTS
Abc           @1  NONAME
Xyz            @2 NONAME
```

We have to use only ordinal no of the function in c# aplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the DllImport attribute, you can specify the Ordinal of the function:

```
 [DllImport("dllname", EntryPoint="#123")]
 static extern int MyFunc(int i);
```

then you call MyFunc to call the ordinal 123.

Comment: @vikky you decide a name in c# for the imported function, and use that name from c#